# Concurrent select/delete from table (Oracle), what transaction isolation to choose?

Tags: oracle, transactions

I have an Oracle table "A" where there will be running two transactions concurrently:

**Transaction 1:** Inserts rows into table "A" only if they are not already there. 
(checked by unique row column value, transaction performes INSERT SELECT INTO "A") 
**Transaction 2:** Deletes rows from table "A", AFTER they are processed. They are no updated in "A"

What transaction isolation for transaction 1 would you recommend to me?

**READ_COMMITED** sounds correct to me, but there will be delays regarding waiting on T2.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Oracle only has two transaction isolation levels-- read committed and serializable.  If you're worried about waits, serializable is only going to cause more wait time so I'm not sure what you're thinking.  I'm also not clear why there would be any relationship between the two transactions unless 2 is deleting rows that 1 is trying to insert or if you're rapidly recycling the "unique column value" so that 2 is trying to delete a row with the same unique value that 1 is trying to insert.  But neither of those seem to make sense.

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for reply. Yes, I want to be sure that T1 won't insert a row with unique column value that is already there in table "A". T1 is inserting via INSERT-SELECT where "select" performes NOT EXISTS check against "A". T2 deletes rows from "A" concurrently...So you're saying that I'm going to be okay with READ_COMMITED?

Comment: Read committed will create the least amount of locking (assuming there is a difference).  I'm still confused about the mechanics, though.  If your "unique value" is, say, a sequence-generated key, you'd only have possible conflict if your sequence had cycled and was trying to re-use a value that 2 hadn't yet cleaned up yet.  That would be a very (very) scary design.  If that's what you're building, I would be rather concerned for reasons far beyond the transaction isolation level.

Comment: That "unique column value" will be for example contract_number. I want to be sure that there will be only one row with this contract number in "A", for example. So no, no generated sequence. Thanks for reply, READ_COMMITED should be fine for me.

Comment: Unless that `contract_number` is being deleted by 2 while you're trying to insert it again in 1, I don't see any reason to expect there to be contention between the two (assuming proper table design) regardless of the transaction isolation level.  If you are reusing contract numbers that quickly, you have other issues.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!. No there won't be two sessions deleting one contract_number. It won't be reused that quickly, just can happend every now and than.